# Looking for book or edition name

Tags: figure-de-style, titres

Bonjour !

I'm desperately looking for this book title or even the name of this edition. We have been given copies but not the reference.

I would be glad if someone could help.

Merci d'avance !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *[Français méthodes et techniques : classes des lycées](https://enseignants.nathan.fr/catalogue/francais-methodes-et-techniques-classes-des-lycees-livre-licence-numerique-i-manuel-20-9782091670973.html)*, edited by Nathan.

The content might have substantially evolved between the version you show and the current one though.